# IPhone Call record - win 10 Bluetooth Connection

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, voice-recording

I have IPhone and want to record phone call as voice file.
But this feature is diabled on iPhone for some reasons.
I think to get help from PC's speaker and microphone and make PC (win 10) as bluetooth handsfree and try to record voices on PC.
How can I do it? How can I setup this type of Bluetooth connection on win 10?
Any suggestion or idea?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't it illegal to do this?

Comment: something need TBD: 1) confirm whether win10 Bluetooth stack have HF profile(I assume not) or have RFCOMM and SDP read/write API, 2)if have RFCOMM/SDP read/write API, you need write a single HFP application 3)the most importantly is that you need confirm the audio data path, i.e. via PCM or SCO over UART, what's the SCO handle mechanism on win 10.